# Calculate number of elements to be evaluated

Tags: arrays, math, logic

This is a logical Question which is not bound to any specific language.

Does someone know a way on how to achieve the following?

I do have an array of which I can always evaluate a max of 10 elements.
So if the size of the array grows higher than 10, I need to determine which element I can evaluate - **equally distributed**.

Example:

[**87**, 34, **65**, **23**, 98, **45**, **21**, 54, **65**, **235**, 4, **32**, 98, **42**, **17**]

The bold ones could be the ones considered.

And I do want to always evaluate the highest amount of possibles:

If the length of the array is smaller than 10 THEN evaluate every item.
If the length is higher THEN evaluate 10 out of the array.

If length is 20 -> every 2nd item should be evaluated

If length is 100 -> every 10th item should be evaluated

But what if length is 13 or 27?

Comment: What do you mean by "equally distributed", exactly ?

Comment: The distribution should be even which shall be shown by the highlighted ones in the example. Just taking the first 10 would not be right.

Comment: That's still a very vague description - perhaps you could give some examples for different values of `i` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function which remaps your index 0..9 to an evenly distributed index form 0..n-1, e.g.

```
int map_index(int i,  // index: 0..9
              int n)  // no of elements in array
{
    return i * (n - 1) / (10 - 1);
}
```

Comment: Works, but return value needs to be rounded carefully. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the ones with the indices floor(k*length/10), where k=1, 2, ... 10?
For length 15 this will result indices 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15 - almost matching your example.